# Django urls.py not including the path

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm relatively new to python and trying to make a  django app. Can someone explain me why I'm running in to this issue with the include statement? The sql server says no module named 'website'. I think the problem is with the project structure, but I could not understand how to fix it.

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    # path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    # path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
    
]
```

urls.py file in website folder

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(website.urls))
]
```

urls.py  file in crm folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typo error and a missing import.

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

# First, import your urls file
# Note that urls end with "s"
from website import url as website_urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls,

    # Then, just include it
    path('', include(website_urls))
]
```

**Note:** Next time, please post code not screenshots.

Comment: Yes that worked, Thank you very much. I will make sure to add codes next time instead of images.

Comment: You can still edit your question to put code instead. ;)